# Subclassing UIControls for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uicontrol

By which methods can UIControl properties be extended?

Answer (score 0):

This should help things get rolling:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol#1968627

> Override the `sendAction(_:to:for:)` method of an existing subclass to observe or modify the dispatching of action methods to the control’s associated targets
>
> Override the `beginTracking(_:with:)`, `continueTracking(_:with:)`, `endTracking(_:with:)`, and `cancelTracking(with:)` methods to track touch events occurring in the control.